# Why is not this element with position absolute and top 0 in the top of its container?

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplius-pack/512/list1-128.png" id="img-header"></img>
         <h3 id="header-title">this is just a title</h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the style:

```
#container {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
#img-header {
    width:5%;
    height:70%;
}
#header-title {
    width:90%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

But header-title is positioned below the img.

Since header-title has position:absolute and top:0, I thought it should start where the image
starts.

Why is that happening and how to position it the top?

Comment: Are you sure you want `#header` to have `position:absolute`? Normally in this instance I would expect to see `position:relative` so that its child elements are postioned relative to it. I.e `#header-title` would be  postioned to the top of `#header`. Also, as I always say in these instances, get to know the tools of the trade, Chrome Developer Tools and/or Firebug for Firefox. Use these tools to inspect your suspect elements and find out what styles are affecting them. These tools also viuslaise Padding and Margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h3` is given a top margin by the user agent's default style sheet; you need to zero that out (or use another element instead).

Comment: Also watch out for any inherited padding.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a jsfiddle for you if it's what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/2dvcam8f/12/

I just changed the `margin-top` of `#header-title` since `h3` has it set by default (you can see it in Element Inspector)